# Azure Logic Apps pricing

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have the following logic app:

[image: Logic app design]

Briefly, When a file is created on OneDrive (the trigger):

- If the file content-type is not 'application/pdf', then the app terminates.
- If the file content-type is 'application/pdf' it sends an email & then deletes the file from OneDrive.

The above logic app has 1 trigger & 4 actions.
From MS we have the following pricing:

> **PRICE PER EXECUTION**
>
> Actions   €0.000022
>
> Standard Connector    €0.000106
>
> Enterprise Connector  €0.000844

From my understanding and if I am not mistaken, the plan has 2 Standard Actions (Send email & Delete file) and 2 Built-in actions (the Condition & the Terminate one).

My questions are the following:

1. If the file on the OneDrive is not PDF (and as such runs the Condition and then the Terminate actions) will MS charge only the 2 Built-in actions (2 * €0.000022) or it will charge the 1 built-in (condition) + the 2 standard ones (€0.000022 + 2 * €0.000106) or directly all the actions of the plan which are 2 built-in + 2 standard ones (2 * €0.000022 + 2 * €0.000106)?
2. Aren't the triggers being charged at all?
3. Is it occurring any charge when the plan execution is skipped (like bellow) in case no file is created on OneDrive? (keep in mind that the trigger checks for items [new files] every 1 min.).

[image: Skipped plan executions]

Answer (score 1):

> If the file on the OneDrive is not PDF

According to my understand, your logic app will execute `When a file is crested`(€0.000022) + 'Condition'(€0.000022) + `Termiate`(€0.000022).

> Aren't the triggers being charged at all?

According to my understand, `Trigger` is regarded as a special action, each execution will cost €0.000022.

[image]

> Is it occurring any charge when the plan execution is skipped (like bellow) in case no file is created on OneDrive?

You can click in to check the operation and check whether the `Trigger` is triggered, check if the right side of the action is ticked. If Trigger is executed (the right side is ticked), charges will be charged for each execution of Trigger.

By the way, regarding this issue, you'd better seek official technical support(free of charge), and the answer is more authoritative.

[image]